# Round div with child div at the axis

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a design i'm trying to recreate using html and css 
[image]

and this is what i have been able to create so far

[image]

this is my html structure
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJg6Q.png): 
my current html structure looks like with the round borders . when i try to position the inner div at the edges of the round border as in the design the 
inner div images get cut. please can you help me fix this 
thanks

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="tshirt">image</div>
    <div id="tshirt">image</div>
    <div id="bag">image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add proper code here.

Comment: Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: here is the code https://pastebin.com/embed_js/t9B1FuVd

Comment: show us your entire code ? including css

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

```css
.outercircle {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed purple;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.item img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.item-1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: -50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item-2 {
  top: 50%;
  right: -50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item-3 {
  left: 50%;
  top: -50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.item-4 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.item:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outercircle">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice of you that you have showed him how he could do it but it seems like he didn't do self effort.

Comment: @PatrickMlr, i think he needs to write alot of code in order to get the desired results :) . I wanted him to start correctly.